# PC only boots partially or not at all anymore, has gotten worse, what could be the cause?

Tags: boot, power-supply

I have an older PC with Core i7 4790K on an Asus Z97 board, a GTX 980, and a 500 W 'be quiet!' Pure Power power supply. As most PCs it boots up in a sequence of fans on high, fans to low, ASUS boot screen, Windows loads. However it recently started getting stuck at the fans on high step, with no boot screen appearing, I have to do a hard shut down. Other times it gets to the ASUS bios boot screen, but it takes long to appear, and then it just reboots, and gets stuck on the 'fans on high' step again. Sometimes nothing happens at all except that the light on the power button turns on when pressed.

This happened occasionally, got more frequent, and now it almost always happens and I need 5+ tries to get it to boot (over a few months). However once Windows is loaded there are no problems as far as I can tell.

The only thing I tried is resetting the RAM in the sockets. What could the cause be? Is the power supply failing?

Added later: It now only starts up the fans for one second, shuts down, and repeats. I switched out the power supply, did not help.

Comment: Symptoms points to overheating or other issues. Clean up everything and eventually replace thermal paste would be my suggestion. I can have other causes though.

Comment: This is rigth after turning it on in the morning, that can't be overheating?

Comment: Yes, it can be. But capacitors failing is also very plausible and so are many other hypotheses. Such problems are almost impossible to diagnose by asking the internet. Better find an electronics professional person and have it all checked.